# Python AST - Detect illegal tokens in the expression

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, abstract-syntax-tree

How should I optimize the `compile()` function (parser) to:

1. Only accept tokens: `'numeric string (integer)'`, `ADD`, `SUB`, `MUL`, and `DIV`
2. Detect illegal token/expression with error display (stop immediately):

   `ERROR: Unexpected token at # 4`
3. `ADD`, `SUB`, `MUL`, and `DIV` must expect exactly two tokens:

> [`'numeric string (integer)'` or `ADD` or `SUB` or `MUL` or `DIV`]

> and

> [`'numeric string (integer)'` or `ADD` or `SUB` or `MUL` or `DIV`]

4. The function should calculate the expressions starting from the most inward expression.

---

**CODE:**

```
def is_operator(token):
    return (token in ['ADD', 'SUB', 'MUL', 'DIV'] or token.isnumeric())


# Compiles a list of tokens
# into an abstract syntax tree (AST). 
# 
# A token represents either a number (e.g. "42") 
# or an operator ("ADD", "SUB", "MUL" or "DIV"). 
# 
# A node of the returned AST is either a string 
# that represents a number (e.g. "42") 
# or a tuple in the form of (operator, child1, child2) 
# where child1 and child2 are the subtrees of the AST. 
# 
# This function returns (ast, unprocessed_tokens) 
# where unprocessed_tokens are the tokens yet to compile. 
# 
def compile(tokens):
    if len(tokens) == 0:
        return ('NOOP',)
    token = tokens[0]
    if is_operator(token):
        child1, unprocessed = compile(tokens[1:])
        child2, unprocessed = compile(unprocessed)
        return (token, child1, child2), unprocessed
    else:
        return token, tokens[1:]


line = ['ADD', 'SUB', '2', '2', 'MUL', '6', 'DIV', '10', '2']
print(compile(line)[0])
# => ('ADD', ('SUB', '2', '2'), ('MUL', '6', ('DIV', '10', '2')))
```

---

**SAMPLE # 1:**

Input:

```
line = ['ADD', 'SUB', '3', '2', 'MUL', '6', 'DIV', '10', '2']
```

Expected Output:

```
AST: ('ADD', ('SUB', '3', '2'), ('MUL', '6', ('DIV', '10', '2')))

ANSWER: 31
```

---

**SAMPLE # 2:**

Input:

```
line = ['ADD', '3', '2', '1']
```

Expected Output:

```
ERROR: Unexpected token at # 4
```

---

**PS:**

I am aware of parsing libraries, I will not go in that direction. I need to solve it by just using native python code.

I already coded the `lexer()` function.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Question updated.